# Vaadin Grid Row details

Tags: angular, vaadin-grid, vaadin-elements

Hi there I'm using vaadin grid, is there any live demo for me to see how to use that on my angular 2 client?

I have a table and when I click on the row I want it to show subtable which shows my details table about that row from database SQL server.

I already try from this https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-row-details.html but I still not get it where do we put our HTML table to hide and all that.